# Problem with string transform in dict then add to list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, append

So, I want from a text file transform each string in a dict, and then add each of them to a list. But I have some problems with the append mode.

Here is my code:

```
contenuto_dei_file = [
    'Jund Food\nPioneer',
    'Blue Moon\nModern'
    'Izzet\nPioneer'
]


def parse_decks_content(contenuto):
    d = {}
    decks = []
    for element in contenuto:
        element = element.splitlines()
        d["name"] = element[0]
        d["formato"] = element[1]
        print(d)
        decks.append(d)

    return decks


decks_come_dizionari = parse_decks_content(contenuto_dei_file)
print(decks_come_dizionari)
```

Desired result:

```
decks = [
    { 'name': 'Jund Food', 'formato': 'Pioneer', },
    { 'name': 'Blue Moon', 'formato': 'Modern', },
    {'name': 'Izzet', 'formato': 'Pioneer'}
]
```

My code outputs the following:

```
decks = [
    {'name': 'Izzet', 'formato': 'Pioneer'},
    {'name': 'Izzet', 'formato': 'Pioneer'},
    {'name': 'Izzet', 'formato': 'Pioneer'}
]
```

Why the append don't just add each element to the next and instead override the element before?

Comment: It doesn't overwrite. Quite the opposite, it adds the same element - the reference to the dict `d` - again and again. So your list is just the same dict multiple times and what you see is the results from the last iteration. Try to fix by creating a new dict with each iteration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't overriding, you just have the same dictionary, you should make a new dictionary on each iteration.

Do this instead:

```
contenuto_dei_file = [
    'Jund Food\nPioneer',
    'Blue Moon\nModern'
    'Izzet\nPioneer'
]


def parse_decks_content(contenuto):
    decks = []
    for element in contenuto:
        d = {}
        element = element.splitlines()
        d["name"] = element[0]
        d["formato"] = element[1]
        print(d)
        decks.append(d)

    return decks


decks_come_dizionari = parse_decks_content(contenuto_dei_file)
print(decks_come_dizionari)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a list comprehension:

```
[{'nome': f, 'formato': s} for i in contenuto_dei_file for f, s in [i.split('\n')]]
```

output:

```
[{'nome': 'Jund Food', 'formato': 'Pioneer'},
 {'nome': 'Blue Moon', 'formato': 'Modern'},
 {'nome': 'Izzet', 'formato': 'Pioneer'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Tomerikoo and Tyler have mentioned, you're appending a *reference* to the dictionary to the list, instead of the contents of the list itself.

This means that by the end of the iteration in your example, `decks` contains 3 references to `d` *as it was most recently* - which is `{'name': 'Izzet', 'formato': 'Pioneer'}`.

When this happens, one way of solving the issue is (as people have already mentioned) to create a new dictionary each time you process an element.

Another way is to copy the contents of the dictionary at that time, by using the `copy()` method of the `dict` class:

```py
def parse_decks_content(contenuto):
    d = {}
    decks = []
    for element in contenuto:
        element = element.splitlines()
        d["name"] = element[0]
        d["formato"] = element[1]
        print(d)
        decks.append(d.copy())

    return decks
```

The only potential issue with using `copy` is that it returns a "shallow" copy - if there are mutable objects within the dictionary that you're copying, those can be "overwritten" like you experienced. For this reason I'd recommend creating a new dictionary each time, like in the other answers.

(An explanation of the `copy` method and the difference between "shallow" and "deep" copies can be found here: https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-copy-a-dictionary-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy/)